# behavior subject doesnt udate

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to set my language in the BahaviorSubject using a default value in a LanguageService. My service looks like thi

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as globals from '../../../environments/globals';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {
    languages = globals.languages;

    language = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.languages.polish.code);

    setLanguage(code: string) {
        console.log(code)
        this.language.next(code);
    }

    getLanguage() {
        return this.language.asObservable();
    }
}
```

it is provided by the SharedModule which is then imported by every single component I have.
The problem is that using setlangueage I can see the proper code Im setting, but the getLanguage always returns mi the default value. I've never had a problem with BehaviorSubject before so I'm not sure what can be the cause.

I've implemented

```
this.languageSubscription = this.languageService.getLanguage().subscribe((language: string) => {
            console.log(language);
        })
```

in one of my components to see if it's ok but... it isn't. Any clues?

I think the problem is connected with routing, when I changd to AsyncSubject od normal Subject then on changing the screen I got nothing in getLanguage() like it's never called

Comment: `@Injectable()` is your `LanguageService` a singleton?

Comment: I wanted it to be, because it would be one service for the whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove service from any `providers` arrays and change decorator to:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```

Comment: don't uderstand why but it helped thanks!

Comment: you either had a duplicated provider somewhere accidentally, or you're using lazy loading, which recreates services provided at the module level. root level providers are the recommended method to avoid either of these if your service should be a singleton.